# MVC filter action redirect to infinite loop

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, asp.net-mvc-ajax, asp.net-mvc-filters

I'm trying to create filter, the filter supposed to check role (not asp .NET membership or Identity but my-self one) and my wish is to restrict all controller actions (let call it "AuthController" for the following) from low-role level users.

In my filter condition i remove the restrict user to home page.

The problem occur when i remove the high-role level in Ajax within the AuthController Then my partial view get me to the home page.

is there an elegant way to avoid that?

```
    [HttpPost, ActionName("DeleteRole")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(Guid UserId, Guid RoleId)
    {
        CustomProvider CP = new CustomProvider();
        CP.DeleteRoleFromUser(UserId, RoleId);

        return PartialView("RolesDelete", db.Role.Where(p => p.Id == RoleId).SingleOrDefault());

    }
```

The filter:

```
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);

        if (filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated && string.IsNullOrEmpty(NameFromExternal))
        {
            NameFromExternal = filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
        }
        CustomProvider cp = new CustomProvider();
        if (CustomRoleProvider.Instance.IsUserInRole(cp.getADNameFromFullDomainName(NameFromExternal), eRoles.High.ToString()))
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary { { "controller", "Auth" }, { "action", "Index" } });
            filterContext.Result.ExecuteResult(filterContext.Controller.ControllerContext);
        }
        else
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary { { "controller", "Home" }, { "action", "Index" } });
            filterContext.Result.ExecuteResult(filterContext.Controller.ControllerContext);
        }

    }
```

Comment: What does the code yo have shown got to do with your question? You have not even shown your Filter

Comment: I Wrote what the filter do (condition: high-role continue, low-role go to homepage), the issue is that my action return partial view and this is i dont want to restrict.

Comment: Again, what Filter? You need to show the relevant code in your question.

Comment: Edit my Question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the filter let the unauthrized user to some controller action that refer hot to Home page, and in the partial view set redirection statement that will appear on as a partial page he restricted.

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Redirection(string controller, string view)
    {
        ViewBag.TargetCtrl = "Home";
        ViewBag.TargetView = "Index";
        ViewBag.TargetTitle = "Home Page";
        return PartialView("~/Views/Shared/Redirection.cshtml");
    }
```

**View**

```
You ara redirected to @ViewBag.TargetTitle
<script>
    window.location.href = '@Url.Action(ViewBag.TargetView, ViewBag.TargetCtrl)';
</script>
```

Now the user will redirect to the Home page and wont see the Home Page as partial view.

Answer (score 0):

Why not to allow Ajax queries?

add this to your condition:

```
!filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest()
```

Comment: Isn't it a security issue?